# Dynamic Leaflet layer class

Tags: javascript, svg, leaflet, geojson

This is my scenario: I have a geojson with point features, some with the attribute "ambulance", other "intervention". I will add them on the map with pointToLayer

```
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(cars, {
pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return new L.Marker(latlng, {icon: cssIcon});
    }, onEachFeature: onEachFeature });
```

the cssIcon variable enables me to use SVG for my points.

```
var cssIcon = L.divIcon({
      className: "css-icon",
      html: "<svg> my svg code here </svg>"
      ,iconSize: [20,20]
      ,iconAnchor: [20,20]});
```

Now the problem. I need to add specific classes (based on the features attributes) to this Svgs so I can animate them using the new Web Animation Api. I have tried the following:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
layer.on({
    add: addClass,
})};
```

... where the addClass function should query the feature, check if the feature's attribute is either "ambulance" or "intervention" and add a class accordingly:

```
function addClass(e){
    var layer = e.target;
    if(layer.feature.properties.car_type === "ambulance"){
    L.DomUtil.addClass(layer.defaultOptions.icon.options, "ambulance-class");

}else(layer.feature.properties.car_type === "intervention") {
    L.DomUtil.addClass(layer.defaultOptions.icon.options, "intervention-class");
}};
```

What I get is :

- the layers with the "ambulance" attribute will get the "ambulance-class" class, but ...
- the layers with the "intervention" attribute will get the "intervention-class" and will also get the "ambulance-class" class.

I also tried:

```
 geojson_layer.eachLayer(function (layer) {  
  if(layer.feature.properties.car_type === "ambulance") {    
    L.DomUtil.addClass(layer.defaultOptions.icon.options, "ambulance-class"); 
  }});
```

..but this won't add classes at all. I might be wrong in using `layer.defaultOptions.icon.options` to add the class, but using this I am able to get the object with `document.getElementsByClassName("ambulance-class")`.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call a separate function to create your icon within `pointToLayer`, you can check the feature properties and append the appropriate class to `className` there:

```
function getCssIcon(feature) {
  if (feature.properties.car_type === "ambulance") {
    classTxt = " ambulance-class";
  } else if (feature.properties.car_type === "intervention") {
    classTxt = " intervention-class";
  }
  return L.divIcon({
    className: "css-icon" + classTxt,
    html: "<svg> my svg code here </svg>",
    iconSize: [20, 20],
    iconAnchor: [20, 20]
  });
}

var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(cars, {
  pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
    return new L.Marker(latlng, {
      icon: getCssIcon(feature)
    });
  },
  onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: this is what I ended up doing.